# Is this the right forum for asking about term difference between Git and TFS?

Tags: discussion, support

Sometimes, when I ask an honest question, putting effort in pre-research and phrasing, I still manage to trigger eyebrows-lift from users (carelessly skimming through the text, ill-willingly assuming a bunch of wrong stuff)* so this time I'll make sure to ask if my question is appropriate in this forum, well formulated and clearly stating the issue.

**Yes, it **is** a joke.  And no, that's **not** how I trigger the said eyebrowse-lift.*

---

We've got talking about branching and forking in Git and a teammate asked if there's something like that in TFS. I explained that there is, although it's managed differently (shelfsets, branching, cloning, workspacing). In the end, we couldn't figure out the exact relation between these terms, though, and, despite googling the definitions and guides, we couldn't establish it reliably. I can admit that my competence within Git is limited and I'd guess that their isn't so hot neither.

I've never felt limited managing a project while working with TFS, so I'm assuming that Git's things have their equivalents in it. However, it possible that Git introduces a new trick that I'm not aware of. Please note that I don't mean Git introducing the same concept as already possible in TFS only delivered in an easier or more reliable manner.

Does TFS have the capacity equivalent of branching/forking in Git?

Comment: TFS is capable of hosting Git projects, and supports all of Git's capabilities in this mode, including branching and forking. It is also capable of hosting Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC), the native, centralized, SQL Server-based VCS provided by Microsoft.  The capabilities you're asking about are based on the underlying VCS provider, in other words, not TFS per se.  [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/code/overview) has a pretty good outline of the differences between TFS hosting TFVC and TFS hosting Git.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not to be nit-pick but that wasn't the question. The question was whether this is an appropriate forum to ask such a question, hehe. Nevertheless, great info. I was using the wrong terminology. I need to re-ask it as TFVC vs Git, instead. Should I do it here?

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment, and not as an answer.  BTW, my comment is existence proof of your question's viability.  Also note that these aren't "forums;" most of the rules that govern forums won't work here.

Comment: **[Is Stack Overflow a forum?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/)**

Comment: @Snowman Yes, [Stack Overflow is kind of forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92113/195875). But I understand you asking.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I wasn't asking. See the linked answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Does TFS have the capacity equivalent of branching/forking in Git?

Or

> How to achieve in TFS branching/forking as in Git?

Questions about Software configuration management are marked as on-topic in the Help Center but in this answer of [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go) there is a restriction:

> Question is about using a Tool in a Software Development Workflow
>
> If your question involves how to integrate a tool or type of tool into
>   your workflow or process, then it is likely to be on-topic on
>   Programmers. **Generally, if you aren't asking about how to use a
>   specific feature of a tool, but trying to determine how to use the
>   tool to achieve a well-defined goal, start here.**

So if you just want to know how to use TFS, StackOverflow would probably be better suited. I think you should ask that question on StackOverflow.